# Convert mysql query to json encode

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

i've problem convert query to json encode

This is the code:

```
$list = $this->M_Bio->dataBio();
$data = array();
foreach ($list as $result) {
$row = array();
$row[] = ['name' => $result->fullname];
$row[] = ['position' => $result->position];
$row[] = ['office' => $result->office];
$row[] = ['extn' => $result->phone];
$data[] = $row;
}
$output = array(
"data" => $data,
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Result json encode:

```
{"data": [
["name": "Tiger Nixon","position": "System Architect","office": "Edinburgh","extn": "5421"],["name": "Cedric Kelly","position": "Senior Javascript Developer", "office": "Edinburgh","extn": "6224"]
    ]
}
```

I want the results like this:

```
    {
    "data": [
    {
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
    "name": "Cedric Kelly",
    "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "6224"
    }
    ]
    }
```

What should i do? please help me

Comment: You have shown invalid json `Result json encode:` . JSON can not have key:value pairs in [];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the way you add all of the data into the `$output` array...

```
$row = array();
$row['name'] = $result->fullname;
$row['position'] = $result->position;
$row['office'] = $result->office;
$row['extn'] =$result->phone;
$data[] = $row;
```

This will give you a cleaner result in the output array.

You could build them all in one go...

```
$data[] = array('name' => $result->fullname,
     'position' => $result->position,
...
```

which would be cleaner.